# How to solve this limit problem?

Tags: calculus, limits

Limit of $\frac{\sin(3x)}{\tan(2x)}$ as $x$ tends to $0$.

Comment: [Here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-calculus/derivative-applications/lhopital-rule/v/introduction-to-l-hopital-s-rule) is an introduction to L'Hopitals rule.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Using L'Hopitals rule for this is rather overkill.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Yes, but if you are familiar with trig derivatives, it can be solved pretty quickly using L'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(3x)}{\tan(2x)}
=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(3x)}{\frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)}}
=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{\frac{\sin(3x)}{3x}}{\frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}}\cdot{\cos(2x)}
=\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1}\cdot\cos0=\frac{3}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

We'll use Lhospital's rule:
$\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{\sin(3x)}{tan(2x)}}=\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{cos(3x)\cdot3}{sec^2(2x)\cdot2}}=\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{3cos(3x)cos^2(2x)}{2}}=\frac{3}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Without l'Hopital rule:
$$\frac{\sin 3x}{\tan 2x} = \frac{\sin 3x}{3x}3x\cos 2x\frac{2x}{\sin 2x}\frac{1}{2x}$$
Using 
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$
We have
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin 3x}{\tan 2x} = \frac{3}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You may use the equivalency rules as follows.

$$\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\sin(3x)}{tan(2x)}}=\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{3x}{2x}}=\frac{3}{2}$$